# CNAME not working response 403 forbidden

Tags: domain, cname-record

I have created the CNAME (test.mycompanyname.com) for one domain (test.example.com). We have just configured CNAME alone like below,

test.mycompanyname.com  CNAME  test.example.com

When we try to give "test.mycompanyname.com" in address bar, it will response 403 Forbidden error message.

How to resolve this problem?

Regards,
Karthik.

Comment: You're hitting your webserver.  You need to look into file permissions and/or webserver configuration on whatever computer(s) test.mycompanyname.com resolves to.

Answer (score 2):

Errorcode `403` stems from `HTTP`, not from `DNS`. This means that resolving your cname to an ip address of the original domain works fine, but the web server denies the request to view the page.

In your case most likely your http server is not configured properly to serve the request to `test.mycompanyname.com` domain name.

You should create a virtual host or add an alias name to one the existing sites.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please suggest steps to create virtual host or add alias name?

Comment: You can refer to your web server documentation for this. This process differs, depending on what web server you have installed.